# Is there any way in which I can edit "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.css" file?

Tags: html, css, django, python-3.x, bulma

I tried doing it by creating a css file style.css in the same folder, copied the source code of the bulma link provided and then linked it to my html doc. But then, it shows no css features at all.

Comment: You could download it, edit it and then add it to your project / self-host it - you won't be able to edit the file hosted by cloudflare. The better option would be to write your own CSS rules that are loaded after this CSS file, they will take precedence over the rules in this linked file.

Comment: no you cant edit other peoples code. If you copy paste the css you need to include it in your static files. If you have trouble loading your static files please show us the error/project structure. Questions like this without code get generally downvoted. please edit your question

Comment: I would recommend overriding the styles you need to edit - same as @OliverTrampleasure has said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot edit resources that are hosted on our CDN. Many, many sites rely on these resources remaining intact and the same forever!

You can however modify the styling on your site whilst using this resource by first including it in your website's HTML (within in the `head` tag):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-vK3UTo/8wHbaUn+dTQD0X6dzidqc5l7gczvH+Bnowwk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

You can then modify this styling by creating a secondary CSS file locally alongside your site's HTML file, calling it `my-styles.css` for example. You can then also include that on your webpage by using another `link` tag within your `head` tag, after the link for bulma:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-vK3UTo/8wHbaUn+dTQD0X6dzidqc5l7gczvH+Bnowwk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-styles.css" />
```

Hope that helps with what you are trying to achieve!

- Matt.
Community Manager @ cdnjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't achieve what I was trying to do, I guess the only solution is either copying the exact design provided via Bulma link or ending up writing the whole css code all by own which I don't really prefer until essentially needed. So, I'd rather stick to the pre-defined design provided by Bulma.